# What does the clause 'it should' mean in "…has access to resources it should”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does the clause 'it should' mean in "…has access to resources it should”?

> Security involves ensuring that the request only has access to resources it should.

Comment: *the request only has access to resources **which / that** it (the request) should **have access to**.*

Comment: Your answer is the only result that turns up ["Security involves ensuring that the request"](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00CEDZECpyHcYyI4kOndnaRyGMphw%3A1608991199603&ei=30HnX9K7JJzMgwfc1ZXoBg&q=%22Security+involves+ensuring+that+the+request%22&oq=%22Security+involves+ensuring+that+the+request%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECCEQCjoFCCEQoAFQgTNYx0dg5U1oAHAAeACAAZUBiAG9C5IBBDE0LjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiSp5in5-vtAhUc5uAKHdxqBW0Q4dUDCA0&uact=5)

Comment: Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: Security ensures that the request has access only to the resources it should (have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Security involves ensuring that the request only has access to resources **it should**.

I incorporate some of the comments and rephrase the sentence.

> Security involves ensuring that the request has access only to the resources it should **have access to/be given access to**.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

OED

> **Ensure** (v.) **8. To make certain/sure the occurrence or arrival of (an event), or the attainment of (a result); = assure v. 5.**
>
> 1796   E. Burke Two Lett. Peace Regicide Directory France in Wks. (1842) II. 380   *Whether the authority..can ensure their execution.*
>
> 1839   C. Thirlwall Hist. Greece (new ed.) II. 339   *Having taken no precautions to ensure regular supplies.*
>
> 2019    [Baslow Health Centre](https://www.baslowhealthcentre.co.uk/practice-information/how-we-use-your-health-records/): *In practice, this means ensuring that your personal confidential data (PCD) is handled in ways that are transparent*

Security involves **making sure** that...